# .Net drop down menu c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm having and issue with passing a variable from page to page. Here I have a drop down menu that allows two options of Yes or No to be chosen. With the default of Choose.

```
 <form method="post" id="Form" action="/admin/DefCon5">
    <table align="center" style="width: 200px; height: 140px;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5"><img src="/images/logo.png"><br>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div align="center">
        <select  id = "DefCon5" align="center" valign="top" name="DefCon5">
            <option value="Choose">Choose..</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
        <br /> 
        &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
        <textarea align="Center" name="message" value="message" rows="4" cols="40">Please enter a brief message before engaging DefCon5</textarea>
        <br /> 
        <input type="submit">
        </div>
```

Here I take one of those two options( for testing purposes I chose Yes)

```
string yes = Request.Params["Yes"];
string no = Request.Params["No"];
var DefCon5 =  Request["DefCon5"];
string message = Request.Params["message"];
string redirURL = "";


if (DefCon5 == "yes")
{
    Response.Write(@message);
    Response.Write(@Defcon);
    redirURL = "/somepage";
}
else
{

    redirURL = "/DefCon5";
}
```

I'm noticing that the if statement fails because DefCon5 is not reading exactly as yes. I have tried with the variable from the previous page and finally a literal string "Yes". I have also tried a few different Requests with no change. I believe I may be passing Yes/No incorrectly but I'm unclearas to why this is the case.

Comment: Look at it in the debugger, I would expect Request.Params("Yes") to come back as null or empty, the parameter is DefCon5, it's the value that will be Yes or No, I would however have expected that "if(DefCon5=="Yes")" would match.

Comment: This is exactly what it was. My If statement was lowercase. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have changes like this in your controller code

```
public ActionResult DefCon5(string DefCon5,string message)
        {
            //string yes = Request.Params["Yes"];
            //string no = Request.Params["No"];
            //var DefCon5 = Request["DefCon5"];
            //string message = Request.Params["message"];
            string redirURL = "";


            if (DefCon5.ToLower() == "yes")
            {
                Response.Write(@message);
                //Response.Write(@Defcon);
                redirURL = "/somepage";
            }
            else
            {

                redirURL = "/DefCon5";
            } 

            // your code here

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! My if statement was reading as "yes" but what was being in was "Yes"